# Postgres - page by group

Tags: sql, postgresql, pagination

Say I have some data:

```
id  |                stage | name
----+----------------------+------
  1 |          pyramid     | act 1
  2 |          pyramid     | act 2
  3 |          pyramid     | act 3
  4 |          other stage | act 4
  5 |          other stage | act 5
  6 |          other stage | act 6
  7 |          other stage | act 7
  8 |          shangri la  | act 8
```

and I want to load that data into my UI using pagination - but I want the pagination to work on group not row count - what is the best way to achieve this?

So page 1 (if grouping by section_id) would yield:

```
  1 |          pyramid | act 1
  2 |          pyramid | act 2
  3 |          pyramid | act 3
```

Comment: Do you want it dynamic or is section_id sequential without gaps?

Comment: if it is, there will be just `where section_id=$page_number` ,  $page_number comes as a parameter

Comment: Sorry that was just data I'd copied from another random post. There is no sequential section_id I'm afraid. The data i need to page is also the result of a large chunk of Sql.

Comment: What I guess I would need would be the ability to assign a sequential number to the groups...

Comment: I've updated the sample data to better reflect my situation @JakubKania

Comment: I've updated the sample data to better reflect my situation @cur4so - would only let me @ one person at a time :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can specify the criteria for exactly what you want, then just use a filter in the WHERE clause:

```
select *
from data
where stage = 'pyramid';
```

Otherwise, if you want page numbers, you need to determine what is the rank of your grouping criteria. You could do:

```
select *
from data
where stage = (
  select stage
  from (
    select stage, row_number() over ()
    from data
    group by stage
    order by stage
    ) s
  where row_number = <page number>
  )
```